# Copy Paste not working in my Flutter Overlay android App

Tags: flutter, copy, flutter-dependencies, copy-paste, paste

I am using an Android plugin for displaying flutter app over other android apps: [android_window 0.1.1](https://pub.dev/packages/android_window), Some functionalities are still missing in the Overlay Widget, not in the home, the most important for me is the Copy Paste, I can't Copy paste using Clipboard.setData or other Plugins, This is a simple code example reproducing the issue: [Github](https://github.com/nickolaylo/overlay_project_exemple), I am testing using my Huawei P20 Lite.

Any little help will be very welcome, Thank you in advance.

Comment: use Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: text));
and import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

Comment: I did, it's not working properly, working in the home of my app not in the Overlay Widget, please visit the GitHub example I provided above